# $[A,B]=0$ and $[B,C]\neq 0$, what can be said about $[A,C]$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Essentially the title. In particular I'd like to understand if it is possible for $[A,C]=0$, and if so, under what conditions is it possible. If $[A,C]=0$, does this imply $A=cI$, with $c$ some constant?

Comment: Consider $A=I$ and $A=B$.

Comment: Of course! $A=I$ slipped my mind when typing out the question. $A=B$ doesn't work since $[A,C]=[B,C]\neq 0$. I edited my question to include the $A=I$ case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Here is a less obvious counterexample:
$$
J=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},\ A=\pmatrix{J&0\\ 0&J},\ B=\pmatrix{0&I_2\\ 0&0},\ C=\pmatrix{0&0\\ I_2&0}.
$$
We have $[A,B]=[A,C]=0\ne[B,C]$ but $A$ is not a scalar matrix. It is not even diagonalisable.